# Computer vision (Alignment using opencv c++), getting error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am trying to use `getPerspectiveTransform` or `getAffineTransform` function in Visual Studio but when I run the code this message appears to me and the code don't work well at all.

This is a part of my code:

```
    //Mat im_src = imread("img_name.png",-1);
    // Five corners of the source image
    vector<Point2f> pts_src;
    pts_src.push_back(Point2f(106, 115));
    pts_src.push_back(Point2f(141, 111));
    pts_src.push_back(Point2f(129, 134));
    pts_src.push_back(Point2f(109, 150));
    pts_src.push_back(Point2f(147, 146));


    // Read destination
    // Five corners of the book in destination image.
    vector<Point2f> pts_dst;
    pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(30.2946, 51.6963));
    pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(65.5318, 51.5014));
    pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(48.0252, 71.7366));
    pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(33.5493, 92.3655));
    pts_dst.push_back(Point2f(62.7299, 92.2041));

    // Calculate Homography
    Mat h = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(pts_src, pts_dst);
    //The error is due to the previous line 
    // Output image
    Mat im_out;
    // Warp source image to destination based on homography
    Size imgSize(112, 96);
    warpPerspective(img, im_out, h, imgSize);

    // Display images
    imshow("Source Image", im_src);
    imshow("Warped Source Image", im_out);
```

This is the error that occurs:

[image: This is the error that occurs]

Answer (score 0):

According to opencv documentation:

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#Mat%20getPerspectiveTransform(InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst)

```
cv::getPerspectiveTransform()
```

Uses two 4-element vectors. You passed 5-element vectors - taht could be source of your problem.  If you want to use more points you should consider

```
cv::findHomography()
```

With RANSAC flag

Comment: thanks it is helpful in addition i have to change Point2f to only Point